# WordPress echo out array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following line of code: `$terms = get_the_terms( $the_post->ID, 'posts_tags' ); echo $terms;` The idea is to echo out the array in the format of the tags but instead it just returns the word Array?

How do I do this? The tags should be presented like this: 'tag1, tag2, tag3'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
foreach($terms as $term){
    echo $term;
}
```

you might want to add something to separate them, like a `$echo ","` or something, but you get the idea
You can also use this

```
$termsString = implode (',' , $terms);
echo $termsString;
```

As requested:

The terms is indeed an array, see for instance @ProdigySim 's answer for how it looks. You could indeed print them for debuggin purposes with `var_dump` or `print_r`, but that would not help you in a production environment.

Assuming that it is not an associative array, you could find the first tag like this:

```
echo $terms[0]
```

and the rest like

```
echo $terms[1]
```

Right up until the last one (`count($terms)-1`).
The foreach prints each of these in order. The second, as you can find in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) just makes one string of them.

In the end, as you asked in the comments: Just paste this.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $the_post->ID, 'posts_tags' ); 
$termsString = implode (',' , $terms);
echo $termsString;
```

Comment: This is correct. You might explain that `$terms` is an Array, and can't be directly `echo`'d.

Comment: I thought cameron already had that in the question, but I can add something

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Cameron knows it's an Array, but not that it can't be used as such. No big.

Comment: Okay I'm not getting this :/ Could you show the code in full as I'm just not following. Thanks.

Comment: Just past the second code instead of the `echo $terms`. I'll post a "complete" example, but you didn't give me much to work with...

Comment: I get this error with your code: `<br />
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b>/nfs/c03/h07/mnt/52704/domains/creathive.net/html/wp-content/themes/creathive/page-edit-post.php</b> on line <b>91</b><br />`

Comment: That should be something else, this is all quite basic, your obviously pasting this in something bigger (it looks like you're trying to add something to wordpress).

Comment: This is the full page of code: http://pastebin.com/PG9324QS as you will see I'm trying to show the tags inside the textarea.

Comment: Can't think of anything wrong with above. Reduce it to a small problem. try the foreach if you like. Test out little increments.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

```
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
print_r ($a);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
)
```

Comment: Cameron said he wanted to display the items like "item, item, item", so he is actually looking for a method that will iterate over the array, and display the terms with formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are an amazing feature in every programming language I've ever used.  I highly suggest spending some time reading up on them, especially if you're customizing wordpress.

The reason it only echos array is because echo can only return strings.  Try print_r($terms) or var_dump($terms) for more information.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php