# PHP: Separate array with commas

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that should display a list of values from an array followed by a comma and space! However I don't want the last one to have a comma and space after it.

So for example I want `tag1, tag2, tag3` instead of `tag1, tag2, tag3,`

This is my code:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $the_post->ID, 'posts_tags' );
                                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                                    echo $term->name;echo ", ";
                                } ?>
```

Comment: You've asked this before.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358001/wordpress-echo-out-array

Comment: Different question! I'm asking how to remove the last comma!

Comment: but the answer is still `implode`. check @rocket's answer for instance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$output = array();
foreach($terms as $term){
  $output[] = $term->name;
}
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

Comment: Makes me wonder why a language as php and a framework like wordpress do not have any decent library to do even the most basic operations. Rails -> array.join(", ")

Comment: @Marek: It does.  `implode(', ', $array)`.

Answer (score 1):

It´s an build in php feature called implode -> http://php.net/manual/function.implode.php