# how to get comma separated result from a array

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am getting output in this format

`Array ( [0] => Life [1] => living [2] => Health )`

i want it this output in this format
`Life,living,Health` How to achieve the above output in this format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407381/php-separate-array-with-commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function available in php

```
$yourRequiredString = implode (",", $array);
```